# Blocking numbers in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, contacts

Is there a way to block a phone number that you are either receiving text or calls from in Touch? I have looked in the contacts and it does not seem that you can even block numbers from there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install F-Call as per the bug link provided. This will be able to filter out all unwanted numbers for you. I did read somewhere that this functionality is going to be available in the phones software, but cannot aee it as yet. Hopefully soon though.